# collision --> don't collide with everything like color switch

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics, collision

I made a game like color switch. The only problem that the player collide with every color...

This is the code I took from github:
https://github.com/prometheon/MLNimbleNinja/tree/master/Nimble%20Ninja

I made a lot of changes so I have now colors , and a different game. But using the github code, how can I do that? Where to decide if it should or not collide? And how?

Xcode swift

Comment: You cannot ask people to go sifting through your code when you have a probem.  Provide a minimal complete and verifiable example of your problem, and people will be more than willing to help.

Comment: thanks for the answer, okay I'll take a short part out of my code, where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

in this case, i would use the userData of the sprites.

if you use UIColor or SKColor to color your nodes, just add it to the nodes userData.

```
[node.userData setObject:node.color forKey:@"COLOR"];
```

and in didBeginContact compare the colors for bodyA and bodyB.

```
UIColor *colorBodyA = [contact.bodyA.node.userData objectForKey:@"COLOR"];
```